# Как отправить данные через ServerRpc сразу когда срабатывает OnApplicationPause() на Андроиде?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю игру с мультиплеером используя Netcode For Gameobjects и Unity Relay и столкнулся с такой проблемой: когда Хост сворачивает игру на телефоне то игра у клиентов продолжается, но данные от сервера никакие не поступают (к примеру, таймер, который просто останавливается и возобновляется когда хост возвращается в игру). Чтобы избежать подобного решил включать Паузу у всех клиентов используя OnApplicationPause() и отправляя всем данные, что игра на паузе и должно открываться меню паузы у всех, пока хост не вернется, используя следующий код:

```
private NetworkVariable<bool> _gamePaused = new(false); //Identification for game pause
public bool gamePaused { get => _gamePaused.Value; set => _gamePaused.Value = value; }

void OnApplicationPause(bool pauseStatus)
{
    if(IsHost && pauseStatus){
        EnablePauseWindowServerRpc(pauseStatus);
    }
}

[ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]
private void EnablePauseWindowServerRpc(bool pauseStatus)
{
    gamePaused = pauseStatus;
}
```

И, соответственно, в апдейте открываю или закрываю окно паузы у клиентов в зависимости от значения переменной pauseStatus. Но! ServerRpc запрос не срабатывает как только Хост свернул окно/игру (как должно), а только когда он снова возвращается в игру! Т.е. когда хост не активен - ничего по сути и не работает..

Перерыл кучу информации в сети и видел не мало подобных вопросов, однако решения так нигде и не увидел :( Помогите разобраться и куда копать или что с этим можно сделать?

Comment: Вероятно во время срабатывания события передача данных для приложения уже не паузе. То есть только указанными средствами это не решить.

Comment: В [доках](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.2/api/Unity.Netcode.NetworkManager.html?q=background) указывается, что флаг `NetworkManager.runInBackground` играет роль и я на знаю, как он относится к `Application.runInBackground`, который `This property is ignored on Android and iOS.`, но может быть работает, через `PlayerSettings.runInBackground`, если связь или зависимость вообще есть. Описание слишком скромное, нужно самому тестить на смартфоне и пк, что бы разобраться.

Comment: @aepot а какими средствами решать? Попробовал через EventHandler - результат тот же: срабатывает только когда хост уже возвращается в игру.. ((

Comment: @Yaroslav перерыл все настройки - для андроида такой опции нет ((